# How to create a custom profile plugin

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, joomla-api, profile

I want to write my own custom profile plugin, but the problem is that the available tutorials ([here](https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin) and [here](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/user-profile/copy-user-profile-plugin)) are a little outdated.

Right now I'm looking at the `setFieldAttribute()`, the last argument is `$group`, and the documentation says:

> string  $group      The optional dot-separated form group path on which to find the field.

And a usage example is this:

`$form->setFieldAttribute('address1', 'description', 'PLG_USER_PROFILE_EI_FILL_FIELD_DESC_SITE', 'profile');`

Do I need to change the value to the name of my plugin or is it the same (`'profile'`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group refers to a named fieldset element inside a form definition.  Find the field you are trying to edit into the form definition and get the name of its parent fieldset element and use that for the group.